# How to export full database own its name in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

How to get database name and export database into the file with that database's name using codeigniter ?

When I try this way, backup file is created, but it is not saved with database name.

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$prefs = array(     
                'format'      => 'zip',             
                'filename'    => 'my_db_backup.sql'
              );
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 
$db_name = 'backup-on-'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
$save = 'pathtobkfolder/'.$db_name;
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file($save, $backup); 
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($db_name, $backup);
```

Comment: What is wrong with your backup now? Your poor English makes question unclear.

Comment: @svgrafov sry i want export by my db name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$NAME=$this->db->database;
$this->load->dbutil();
$prefs = array(
'format' => 'zip',
'filename' => 'my_db_backup.sql'
);
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
$db_name = $NAME.'.zip';
$save = 'public/uploads/'.$db_name;
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file($save, $backup);
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($db_name, $backup);
```

Comment: This is unlikely to help future readers. Explain why this is what the asker is looking for. If you understood the question, consider updating it to be more in line with English grammar.

Comment: @svgrafov look after the code they describe what they want